# How to move a shape based on Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I have written a function to get the ID of shape on click event. I want to create a shape on mouse-move based on ID retrieved by click event.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 800)
                    .attr("height", 803);

            var $stageContainer = $("#content");
            var stageOffset = $stageContainer.offset();
            var offsetX = stageOffset.left;
            var offsetY = stageOffset.top;
            console.log(offsetX + " " + offsetY);

            function getId(Id) {
                $('a').on("click", function () {
                    var shapeId = this.id;
                    console.log(shapeId);
                    return shapeId;
                }).on('mousemove',function(shapeId)
                {
                    if(shapeId == "newTask")
                    {
                        console.log("shape is newTask");
                        function createCircle();
                    }
                })
            }
            function createCircle() {
                svg.append("circle")
                        .attr("id", "onCircleDragStart")
                        .attr("r", 25)
                        .attr("cx", d3.select(this).attr("cx"))
                        .attr("cy", d3.select(this).attr("cy"))
                        .classed("dragTarget", true)
            }
```

However, it isn't working. How do I create a shape on mousemove based on ID retrieved?

```
<div id="content">
            <div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
                <div style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: top; border-right: 2px solid darkcyan;" id="sidebar">
                    <div><a id="newTask" title="Add new task" draggable="true"><img src="task.png" /></a></div>
                    <div><a id="newGateway" title="Add new gateway" draggable="true"><img src="gateway.png" /></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter of the callback of the `on` method of jQuery is the event  captured when the `mousemove` event happened, that's why `shapeId` will never be "newTask" (if you do a `console.log(shapeId);` in the mouseover handler, you should see an event object instead of a string).

You should store the value of shapeId in the scope where both `click` and `mouseover` handlers are defined, for example:

```
function getId(Id) {
    var shapeId;
    $('a').on("click", function (event) {
        shapeId = this.id;
        console.log(shapeId);
    }).on('mousemove',function(event)
    {
        if(shapeId == "newTask")
        {
            console.log("shape is", shapeId);
            function createCircle();
        }
    })
}
```

PS: I didn't test it, let me know if it works.

Comment: Inside `createCircle()` how do I pass x and y coordinates based on distance mouse moved?